# Open pdf files in webview according to tableview row selected

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, pdf, uiwebview

I retrieve all data from an sqlite database. I can get them to populate the table view. When I click on a row the webview opens but doesn't show the pdf file.The view is just plain white background. no crash, no errors, simply doesn't show anything.
This is my code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#import "PdfTableVC.h"
#import "PdfVC.h"

@interface PdfTableVC ()

@end

@implementation PdfTableVC {
NSMutableArray *listOfPdf;
}

@synthesize pdfTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self initDatabase];
[self getPoints];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

-(void)initDatabase{
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.db"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (success)
{
    return;
}
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.db"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!success)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}

-(void)getPoints{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my.db"];
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM file_geositi";

    sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement;


    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &searchStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        listOfPdf = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            NSString *pdf = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement,0)];


            [listOfPdf addObject:pdf];


        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement);
}
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [listOfPdf count];
}

//Table View cell
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier =@"pdfCell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [listOfPdf objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

//Detail View items
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPDF"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.pdfTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
     PdfVC *destViewController = (PdfVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
     destViewController.dataPdf= [listOfPdf objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
 }
}
```

**PdfVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PdfVC : UIViewController

//UIWebView
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dataPdf;

@end
```

**PdfVC.m**

```
#import "PdfVC.h"

@interface PdfVC ()

@end

@implementation PdfVC
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize dataPdf;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//No sure about this and in fact makes the app crash   
NSString *pdfName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.dataPdf description]];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pdfName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];


}


@end
```

Any help? Thanx

Comment: Trace out the path of the PDF in the log and see if you are getting the right URL. And please paste a sample URL in your question above.

Comment: log just says "pressed cell number 1, 2" and so on...
All pdf files are in a folder called PDF.

Comment: well you have to put a NSLog statement and actually trace out the path of the PDF before you segue into your PDFVC controller. Trace out what value you are setting into the dataPdf property and see if you are getting the right path for the PDF. Or do it when you are adding the paths into your listOfPdf array. See if you are getting the right paths first.

Comment: And also post code of how you are loading the PDF into your webview.

Comment: Code is only this one. Plus I'm putting property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dataPdf; in the PDFVC Controller.I'm obviously doing something wrong here or missing something.

Comment: That's just an outlet and a property. You actually have to write more code to load a URL into the webview. I'm sure there are tons of tutorials out there to show you that. Also, you must debug your code and put breakpoint a to see what values are passed over or write additional log statements to suit your need.

Comment: All tutorials I've found so far hadn't been helpful. Any suggestion? Thanx @GurtejSingh

Comment: Can you please post code of your PdfVC controller and show us what you have tried to load the PDF into the webview? Will take it from there. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the code with the PdfVC controller @GurtejSingh

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, can you please upload your project and share a link, I'll have a look. Thanks.

Comment: No worries @GurtejSingh, Im a bit busy myself. I'll try to upload it over the weekend

Comment: @GurtejSingh I've uploaded the project to Dropbox: http://www.dropbox.com/sh/vh1uyidljtc0r11/AAClkId3ADwUopvrGjgRXtAma?dl=0 let me know if you can open it.
Thanx

Comment: Got it! Will have a look and get back. Thanks.!

Comment: I was able to fix your issues. Please see my answer below. Please do not forget to vote up and accept the answer if it works for you. In case you need more help, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after having a look at your code, I found the following things:

- You are storing your PDF names in a SQLite database (I don't really
  understand the purpose of doing this, but let's say you need to) with
  the names 'pdf_1', 'pdf_2' and 'pdf_3', but these are not matching
  with your actual file names of PDF's in your supporting files folder
  which are 'PDF 1' etc.
- Secondly, you are passing just the name of the PDF extracted from the database onto the `PdfVC`, which actually does nothing, you have to actually load the PDF into the `webView` here, so it actually does nothing.

**Solution:**

- Rename your PDF's from 'PDF 1' etc to 'pdf_1' etc. so that they match with the actual names stored in your database, or rename the entries in your database to match the file names of the PDF.
- Secondly, place the following code into your `viewDidLoad` method of the `PdfVC` view controller:

  ```
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:dataPdf ofType:@"pdf"];
  NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
  [webView loadRequest:request];
  ```

All this code is doing is that it picks up the right PDF from the resources using the name stored in the property `dataPdf` (passed via the segue) and then loads that PDF into the `webView`.

I would recommend you to re-consider the purpose of an actual database here, since all you are doing is storing the names of the PDF's into the table. It may not be required at all, and you could maintain an `NSArray` of the PDF names in your `PDFTableVC` view controller.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanx, it's working in this example. In real life I need to show 148 pdf files, that's why I'm using a database. The problem is that in the actual app I'm getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter' when I select a table view cell

Comment: That means that one of your PDF is either not matching the name between the database and the support resources, or the PDF does not exist. Please double check. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I've tried with other files those were corrupted that's prob why I got that error.

Comment: Is there a way to then send the content of the webview (pdf in this case) via mail or post on fb, etc?

Comment: PDF files can vary in size, and can get large in file size, so sharing them directly is not going to be a good idea. The way I would do it is that I would store these files on a server and store the URL of each file in the database in a new column. When you share the file, share the URL of the PDF which can be accessed then from the URL. Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Thats the idea, yes. Thanx a lot, really appreciated your help!!

Comment: No problem at all :) let me know if you need any help. Thanks for the up vote :)